# Changing value in list of objects

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a list of objects and I need to loop thru the list and change a value from true to false. Shouldn't a simple for loop do the trick? Am I missing something?

```
var list = [
  { color: 'blue', 'taste': 'sour', 'available': true },
  { color: 'yellow', 'taste': 'bitter', 'available': false },
  { color: 'red', 'taste': 'sweet', 'available': false },
  { color: 'green', 'taste': 'umami', 'available': false }
]

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  if(list[i].available === true){
    list[i].available === false;
  }
}
```

When I return the list though it's giving me the list as it was first captured. Am I using the wrong loop or is it something else?

Comment: Purely a style thing, but why is color an unquoted key when all of your other keys are quoted? Inconsistencies like that have a way of hiding errors...

Comment: `list[i].available === false` is performing a comparison. You need to do an assignment: `list[i].available = false`

Comment: Oh that's just a typo. I was just trying to quickly mock up a bunch of objects in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = [
  { color: 'blue', 'taste': 'sour', 'available': true },
  { color: 'yellow', 'taste': 'bitter', 'available': false },
  { color: 'red', 'taste': 'sweet', 'available': false },
  { color: 'green', 'taste': 'umami', 'available': false }
]

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  if(list[i].available === true){
   // you were not modifying here, just comparing
    list[i].available = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostly nitpicking here but the comparison to `=== true` is not necessary.

Comment: that about solves that question, @Alex Marple i think that was your issue, please mark accepted answer if your good. no point necessary here for anyone (except rishab dev) since the user made a mistake, this is how answers get bloated.  Or im going to guess the first 3 upvotes are rishabh dev? :-)

Comment: Ahhh yes. I knew I was missing something troublingly simple. Thank you. Fixed. I will accept this in 10 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: omg now someone downvoted you.  dude what the heck is happening to the stack crowd here?  lol, thanks for recanting that one..

Answer (score 1):

You are doing comparision using `list[i].available === false`.You need to do assign `false` into `list[i].available`.So, try this `list[i].available = false`.